# Selenium sendkeys - text field getting reset to default value

Tags: selenium, automation-testing, javascriptexecutor

Using Selenium python,I need to enter text in Age field, but unable to achieve after trying below ways.

webdriver sendkeys method and Actions-sendkeys method doesn't work so I tried jsexecutor which performs sendkeys correctly BUT when once i complete rest of the fields on the form which includes drop-downs & textboxes, somehow the age field gets reset to default value . (This doesn't happen when form is filled manually)

`self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = '20'", element)`

To fix above issue, I tried sending Keys.TAB using actions class after entering value in age field, but problem still persists.
`ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(element).send_keys(Keys.TAB*30).perform()`

Tried sending Keys.TAB using jsexecutor as well but no luck.
`self.driver.execute_script(f"arguments[0].value = '\\t'", element)`

Html code of the fields:
`<input class="form-control input-sm controlValid" type="number" value="100"> == $0`

Please suggest

Comment: Could you provide the full code you are working on?

Comment: @soundwave updated the question, please check

Comment: Thanks but i was asking for the full python code, containing the import of the libraries, definition of variables, etc